# Make a pause between images display in openCV

Tags: python, opencv

I would like to show several images, making a pause in between.
I have tried with waitKey, waiting the user to press ESC, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('image1.jpg',0)
cv2.imshow('image',img)


# here it should be the pause
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
if k == 27:         # wait for ESC key to exit
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

img = cv2.imread('image2.jpg',0)
    cv2.imshow('image',img)
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `cv2.waitKey(0)` will wait until a key is pressed after `imshow()`. 
Print `k` to figure out what is the correct value for ESC on your system.

Comment: "it doesn't seem to be working" -- in what sense? | One obvious issue with the script you show is that there's no `waitKey` after the second call to `imshow`. (So you won't see the second image)

Answer (score 22):

In the code you've posted, `image1.jpg` is displayed and waits for the user to press any key since you've used [`waitKey(0)`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#waitkey). The `0` indicates the program will wait until a user hits a key. You can add the number of milliseconds you want to wait before the second image is displayed in place of the `0`. Once you've pressed a key, `image2.jpg` is read but not displayed since you do not have a `waitKey` after the second `imshow` and the program will exit.

You can try the following code. This code assumes that your "several images" are located in a folder and it displays an image, pauses for 3 seconds and displays the next.

```
import cv2
import os

folder_path = ''#folder path to your images

for path in os.listdir(folder_path):#loop to read one image at a time 
    imgpath = os.path.join(folder_path, path)

    frame = cv2.imread(imgpath, 1)

    cv2.imshow('Window', frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(3000)#pauses for 3 seconds before fetching next image
    if key == 27:#if ESC is pressed, exit loop
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Comment: Is there a way to wait until a special key  ,say "space" key ,has been pressed , then continue ?

Comment: @zionpi
Yep, the variable `key` will contain the ASCII value of the key pressed so you can use the ASCII value for space key which is 32.


The full list can be found here: https://www.asciitable.com/

Use the DEC column for the specific character you want

Answer (score 3):

In the `waitkey()` call  the number is the number of milliseconds to wait for.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a value to [`waitkey()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#cv2.waitKey) will make it pause for the given number of milliseconds. You could use [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to cycle through a list of images.

This script will pause 5 seconds and then display the next image. If escape is pressed it exits.

```
from itertools import cycle
import cv2


for image_filename in cycle(['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg']):
    image = cv2.imread(image_filename, 0)
    cv2.imshow('image', image)

    # Pause here 5 seconds.
    k = cv2.waitKey(5000)

    if k == 27:         # If escape was pressed exit
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use glob module in python to select all files

```
import cv2
import glob # get all files in the directory


images = glob.glob("path_to_files/*.jpg") #get all files with given extension

for img in range(len(images)):
    current_image = cv2.imread(images[img], 1) #cv2.imread(images[i], 0) # for image in grayscale
    cv2.imshow('Display Images', current_image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(300) #change to your own waiting time 1000 = 1 second 
    if key == 27: #if ESC is pressed, exit
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```